# Calculating a baseline probability

Tags: probability

I do have a simple question that I just don't get my head around right now:

Assume I do have

```
A total of 15000 balls
5000  Blue Balls 33%
10000 Red Balls 77%
```

What is the "baseline probability" of predicting the next ball correctly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a Math question and belongs on the Math site: https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "baseline" just means the simplest thing that one could reasonably do. In this case I think most people would agree that the baseline is p(blue) = 0.33 and p(red) = 0.77. I can't imagine another baseline, but that says something about me, not about the problem. Reasonable can and will disagree about stuff like this.

Under standard assumptions such as independent, "fair" samples, it may be impossible to improve on the baseline. That is, it may be impossible to construct a prediction which is more accurate, in the long run. But under nonstandard assumptions, such as taking the physics of balls into account, it may be possible.